# Twilio Send custom Audio bytes using LocalAudioTrack

Tags: twilio, audio-recording, twilio-programmable-voice, voip-android

I am working on `Android VoIP Application` which uses **Twilio Video Conference** API.

---

### Issue:

How to send `custom audio bytes` recorded from AudioRecord to PSTN ?

---

I have already tried one of the example given in [Video-Quickstart-Android](https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-android) i.e. **ExampleAudioSink**.

> I am able to send and receive the bytes that are recorded and played by the WebRtcAudioRecord.

What I want is to send my own Custom recorded bytes in realtime via **[LocalAudioTrack](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/video/releases/1.0.0/docs/LocalAudioTrack.html)**. I have also bypassed the webrtcAudioPlay but can't seem to figure out, how to send my own bytes via LocalAudioTrack.

Here is twilio given workaround;

```
private void connectToRoom(String roomName) {
        ConnectOptions.Builder connectOptionsBuilder = new ConnectOptions.Builder(accessToken)
                .roomName(roomName);

    if (localAudioTrack != null) {
        connectOptionsBuilder
                .audioTracks(Collections.singletonList(localAudioTrack));
    }

    room = Video.connect(this, connectOptionsBuilder.build(), roomListener());
}


private void createAudioTrack() {
    localAudioTrack = LocalAudioTrack.create(this, false, LOCAL_AUDIO_TRACK_NAME);
}
```

Here you can see, I have stopped the sending of WebRtcAudioRecord bytes to PSTN by placing false in the second param of LocalAudioTrack.create, but couldn't figure it out how to send my own Data.

---

- Note: Please don't suggest me to send my bytes using **LocalDataTrack** API because LocalDataTrack API is not maintained yet to send bytes to PSTN.

---

For reference: [video-quickstart-android](https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-android)

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?